# $f(M) = \det(AD-BC)$ for block matrix is alternating $n$-linear function. with respect to rows of $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$$
  M = \pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}
$$

I am trying to prove for $2n \times 2n$ matrix $M$, splitted into $4$ $ n \times n$ matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ in usual way, that $\det(M) = \det(AD - BC)$ (assume all $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ commute).

My idea is to show that function $f(M) = \det(AD - BC)$ is $n$-linear alternating with respect to rows of $M$ and show that $f(I) = 1$ so that $f(M)$ is indeed the unique determinant function for matrix $M$.

I proved that $f$ is $n$-linear and half way proving that $f$ is alternating. I showed that if two rows either with each indices of range $1\ldots n$ or each indices of range $(n+1)\ldots2n$, $f(M) = 0$. But I'm stuck proving that if we take two indices from $1\ldots n$ and $(n+1)\ldots2n$, respectively, $f(M)$ is again $0$ (which would complete the proof that $f$ is alternating).

I tried many combinations of dealing with $DA - BC$, $AD - CB$, etc. But I can't find a key to show this. Can anyone help me proving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Schur_complement) that you have
\begin{align*}
\det(M)&= \det(D)\cdot\det(A-BD^{-1}C)\\
&=\det(AD-BD^{-1}CD)\\
&=\det(AD-BD^{-1}DC)\\
&=\det(AD-BC)
\end{align*}
Using the fact that you can commute $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Yeah, ive seen that but it relies on invertibility of D. And it is quite messy to get around with it. So i thought my way of doing would be a bit interesting and elegant too.

Comment: @RudinWaltersky -- your name suggests that you should be amendable to an analytic approach. Work over $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$) and define $M_n :=M +\frac{1}{n}I$  and $D$ is invertible for all $n\geq N$. You have $\det\big(M_n\big) - \det\big(A_nD_n - BC\big) = 0$  for all $n\geq N$. Take the limit & use continuity of determinant to see this implies the identity irrespective of invertibility of $D$. This is a result about polynomials of a matrix components; Principle of Permanence of Identities then implies that this holds over any field (OP has abstract algebra tag after all).

Comment: @user8675309 can you explain more about continuity of determinants? Do you mean it's continuous wrt its elements? Also, is permanence of identities neccesary in this proof? Since i don't know that so i want my proof be self contained. Finally, thanks for your elegant explanation. Helped understanding a lot. By the way, are there any suggestions on original proof i was trying? Since i feel like i'm almost there, i don't feel like giving up.

Comment: @user8675309 also, does that limit make sense for example trivial field?

Comment: @RudinWaltersky -- this is why I explicitly said **Work over ℂ (or ℝ)** i.e. so you can do basic analysis.  You get other fields courtesy of Principle of Permanence of Identities.  It sounds like this approach is out of reach.

Comment: @user8675309 thanks for reply. Ive done some research on principle of permanence but what i can find is just a historical realm of extending fields. Only theorem-like one is that regarding analytic function. So, my question is, is there a certain key word i can search for so that i can see how this result can be extended from real or complex field into any field(as you said in the first comment)? Or can you give me a brief idea how it works? I have my doubts about it, but yet it would be fascinating if that result holds so i really wanna know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RudinWaltersky supposing you already know a lot about rings, read the (first half of the) chapter on modules in Artin's *Algebra*.  Really what that will tell you is this $\det\big(M\big) - \det\big(AD - BC\big)=0$ is true when $M$ has coefficients in any commutative ring with identity, fields being of particular interest.

Comment: @user8675309 thanks. I'll check it out.